# Simulate cmd+w on windows

Tags: autohotkey

Using autohotkey, I want to simulate hitting <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> on a mac. That is, to close the window.

There's a difference between closing a window (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) and closing a program (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>). I have mapped `#q` to `!F4`. using

```
#q::send !{F4}
```

---

I tried

```
#w::WinClose
```

and

```
#w::WinKill
```

without success.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, closing a window is generally bound to `Ctrl-F4` (`#w::send ^{F4}`).

Using `WinClose`, as [its docs](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinClose.htm) say, requires search parameters or a "last found window" which can be tricky for a non-top window and is unreliable. It is also an unusual method (it send WM_CLOSE instead of going through the app's UI logic - the docs note this too) which can make the application misbehave. So I strongly recommend against using it for this particular task.

Answer (score 1):

Commonly, in windows I use this: `^w::SendInput, ^{F4}`. For your question would be: `#w::SendInput, ^{F4}`.

Have fun using Autohotkey. It's a great tool.

Comment: quick question:  
    ^{F4}::send #t Why is that not an ok command?